# Cannot Get.find repository instance with GETX in flutter app

Tags: flutter, flutter-getx

When I used Get.find() in GetXController to use but it throws error of not found:
Unhandled Exception: "Repository" not found. You need to call "Get.put(Repository())" or "Get.lazyPut(()=>Repository())"

Even though i have already created Bidding as bellow in main:

```
class InitialBindings extends Bindings {
  @override
  void dependencies() {
    Get.lazyPut(() => Repository());
  }
}
```

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(GetMaterialApp(
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    navigatorObservers: [observer],
    initialRoute: Routes.SPLASH,
    initialBinding: InitialBindings(),
    // theme: appThemeData,
    defaultTransition: Transition.cupertino,
    getPages: AppPages.pages,
    home: SavingAllcation(),
  ));
}
```

`and in SavingAllocation:`

```
class SavingAllcation extends StatelessWidget {
  SavingAllcation({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final controller = Get.put(SavingAllocationController());
```

`and GetXController:`

```
class SavingAllocationController extends GetxController {

  final _goalRepo = Get.find<Repository>();
 @override
  void onInit() {
    super.onInit();
    _getGoalCategories();
  }

  Future<void> _getGoalCategories() async {
    List<UserGoalCategory>? goalCategories =
        await _goalRepo.getLastGoalCategories();
  }
```

Comment: As you have used lazy binding. Get.find will not find the controller unless and untill the widget with which UserExpenseGoalRepository is visible on the screen first. It will not initialize, that's the meaning of lazy loading.  If u still want to access, make UserExpenseGoalRepository a global getx controller